# Stats counter with Symfony when i return a file

Tags: php, symfony

With Symfony 6 I have a function in my controller to set a counter+1 when the page is viewing.
When I click on the link on the home page, the counter doesn’t increment... But if I refresh the page, the counter is increment.

Here is my function :

```php
#[Route('/test', name: 'app_test)]
public function test(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
{
    $newView = new testStats();
    $newView->setDate(new DateTime());
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $em->persist($newView);
    $em->flush();
    
    return $this->file("../public/docs/test/test.pdf", null, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
}
```

This is a basic function but I don't understand why when I click, the counter doesn’t increment

Comment: The counter is incremented on the first click, but obviously the new count isn't returned immediately..

Comment: In this very specific case, when you are on a page and the next click returns a file, the browser stays where it is, it doesn’t make a second request to get a new copy of the page it is on.

Comment: Ok so if i understand,this is a cache issue ?

Comment: Otherwise, i can make an AJAX script to increment my counter. But i want to make it in PHP

Comment: I tried with a new controller and a constructor in wich in put my counter setter but it still doesn't work

Comment: This is not a cache issue. Browsers make one request at a time, and servers send a single response. The request results in a file response. Yes, you could make a second request using XHR to get the stat counter.

Comment: humm i tried with ajax Request but i have a NS_BINDING error. And, i tried with a private function call BEFORE the file response, but i have an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
#[Route('/pdf', name: 'app_pdf')]
    public function displayPDF(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, StatsRepository $statsRepo): Response
    {
        $this->pdfStats($doctrine, $statsRepo);
        $pdf = "../public/docs/pdf/doc.pdf";
        $response = new Response(file_get_contents($pdf));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, 'doc.pdf'));
            return $response;
    }

    private function pdfStats($doctrine, $statsRepo): void
    {
        $criteria = array("name" => "pdf");
        $pdf = $statsRepo->findBy($criteria);
        $firstCounter = $pdf[0]->getCounter();
        $incrementcounter = $pdf[0]->setCounter($firstCounter + 1);
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();
        $em->persist($incrementcounter);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).